# Windows built-in cURL

Tags: windows, curl, visual-c++

I need to link my app against the cURL API on Windows 10 with MSVC.  Recently, Microsoft has included cURL, and it can be run from the command line.  Does Microsoft provide a static LIB file or dynamic DLL of their cURL to link against?  I can't find it anywhere.

I know that I can compile my own cURL LIB/DLL for Windows, but would like to use a pre-built binary to guarantee security.  I can get a binary here https://curl.se/download.html but I am not sure those binaries have built in the SSL, (given they want to be SSL agnostic).  Even if they did select a SSL in their binary, which one?  Only certain SSL implementations will work for me.  See section "Availability" in this link: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO_BLOB.html

Thank you for reading!

Comment: What do you mean by "would like to use a pre-built binary to guarantee security"? The Microsoft's version of cURL contained some unpatched critical vulnerability for a long time, see [this](https://borncity.com/win/2022/01/21/windows-january-2022-security-updates-for-curl-vulnerability-cve-2021-22947-a-tough-task-for-security-reporters/), for example.

Comment: I mean that I trust MS to build a LIB or DLL file with the proper SSL more than I trust myself to build it.

Comment: But if I need to build it see this link: https://github.com/curl/curl/tree/master/winbuild

Comment: I was drinking last night and somehow landed here.   So today I went looking to find the LIB file.  What I found was I was in over my head. Is it possible the ATL curl Class may help you?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/curl-class?view=msvc-170

Comment: I don't even know what UWP is.  While I don't know, this guy seemed to know what he is talking about.  https://medium.com/@gal.shelef/building-libcurl-for-universal-windows-platform-9c8d4f2f7240

Comment: Thanks for the links, @Misunderstood!  That and a similar one worked for me: https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/how-to-build-openssl--zlib--and-curl-libraries-on-windows  The fact that there are so many "build libcurl on Windows" links strongly suggests that Windows does NOT provide libcurl built-in or with Visual Studio C++ and we MUST build our own with Visual Studio (or use the gcc binary?)  Cheers!